# Not work tap event for image in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I use MVVM, and have next code in view:

```
<Image Source="Content/img/heart_gray.png" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="0,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding LikeVisability}">
                                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                                                        <cmd:EventToCommand  Command="{Binding SetLikeCommand}" />
                                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            </Image>
```

In viewModel:

private RelayCommand setLike;

```
     public ICommand SetLikeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return this.setLike ?? (this.setLike = new RelayCommand(this.SetLike));
        }
    }


    private void SetLike()
    {
        var t = "fsdf";
    }
```

When i put break point in method SetLike(), program not stoping when i tap image. Maybe i doing something wrong in view, where bind event? Please help!

Comment: put a breakpoint to the setter, does it get called?

Comment: Why not use a button styled to only show the image (no border)?

Comment: I put breakpoint to the setter, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing fundamentally wrong in the code you've shown, it just doesn't show enough to identify your issue.

The following does work:

xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Image Source="Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="0,0,5,0"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding LikeVisability}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                <cmd:EventToCommand  Command="{Binding SetLikeCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

public partial class View : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    private ICommand setLike;

    public ICommand SetLikeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return this.setLike ?? (this.setLike = new RelayCommand(this.SetLike));
        }
    }

    public Visibility LikeVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    private void SetLike()
    {
        var t = "fsdf";
    }
}
```